# If I will be partitioning my Drive, where is the safest place for very Important Files?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

If I will be partitioning my Drive, where is the safest place for the very Important Data Files?

Do you think Partitions with the lower number is safer than Partitions with the higher number, ie: Partition 2 is better than Partition 5?

I've heard that the lower the number, the nearer it is towards the center/core of the disk, and the higher the number, the nearer towards the edge of the disk, is it True?

So if that is the case, if in case the disk would fail, what partitions will be first affected?

Comment: Although an interesting question, IMO you shouldn't be too concerned about it. Modern HDDs especially have gone a long way to maximise performance thanks to advances in technology. What you should be more concerned about is your backup strategy, as well as keeping check of the health of your disks.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, backing up is really important. But just to answer and to satisfy my questioning, which is better, lower number or higher number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some background:

Partition numbers are just numbers. They do not indicate where in the drive the data is stored.

Example: I have an empty, single platter single head drive. Lets represent it as this:

```
  [--------------------------------------------]
Begin/inner part                            Outer part.
of the disk
```

Now I create a partition at the end of the disk.

```
  [--------------------------111111111111111111]
      (The 1's represent partition number 1)
```

Next I create a second partition using the remaining space.

```
  [22222222222222222222222222111111111111111111]
```

If I did this the other way around, with creating a partition 1 at the beginning of the disk and 2 at the rest I would have had a scheme like this:

```
  [11111111111111111122222222222222222222222222]
```

I could even have started with another partition number than 1 or 2. Both 3 and 4 would also have been valid.

Now you might say: "Why not start with number 1, it feels *natural*" and you would be right. Most people will start with 1, then 2, then 3 etc etc. But there is no technical reason. Which means that your question will need to be rephrased as to **disk locations** rather than **partition numbers**.

Ok, so much for background part 1.

---

Background part 2.

Reading your question I get the impression that this question was asked assuming MBR formatting. MBR originally supported four partitions. No more.

These partitions were usually called partition 1, 2, 3 and 4.
Per partition you would give the start of the partition (as head, track, sector), the end of the partition (head, track, sector), some flags (e.g. active/boot-able or not) and a number representing the filesystem on that partition.

Later this got extended. One of the filesystems number did not indicate a filesystem anymore, but a 'this space is used as an extended partition, look here for more partition table information`.  The partition numbers in this extended partition are usually numbers 5 and upward.

Thus if you make two partitions on a disk, one primary and one in the extended you end up with a setup like this:

```
           [11111111111111 444444444444444444444444]
            ^            ^  |                     |
           |             |  |                     |
 Pa 1 ----/  ------------/  |                     |
       (from)          (to) |                     | 
                            |                     |
 Pa 2: Empty                |(from)          (to) |
                            |                     |
 Pa 3: Empty                |                     |
                            |                     |
 Pa 4: Extended substype ---/ --------------------/
        P5: From to
        P6: From to
        P7: From to
        ...

The extended partition would be under divided in much the same way as the primary partition table. However two partitions, one in theprimary table and one in the extended table would usually get partition numbers 1 and **5**. While two partitions as primary on the same disk locations would usually result in partition numbers 1 and **2**.
```

---

OK, enough background. Now to the answer.

In practice it does not matter. Failure on a disk is rarely caused by the platter. In almost all cases it is due to head crashes, actuator loss or stuck bearings. In all cases you loose access to all the data on the disk, regardless of which specific place you used.

And the latter assumes that you can choose, which is not guaranteed. On drive firmware makes its own choices, and those vary per manufacturer and per drive model. Some will start at the inside of a platter and work outward. Other can do the reverse.  Some will logically proceed along one platter and then moves to the next platter. Some will first use all the same tracks on all platter.  There is not way for the end user to influence this.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanations, I've learn a lot Hennes. Its just because I once remember my bestfriend who got her disk malfunctioned, we brought it to a technician, and the guy recovered some files on certain parts of the disk, but not all. Well, maybe its just a coincidence that certain parts cannot be recovered, whilst other parts can be. Anyway, thanks so much.

Comment: If you have a physical head crash (where the disk hits the spinning platter) and the head survives then only part of the disk will be lost. But that 1) mean the head needs to survive. 2) It does not matter where that is on the disk. If you hit the disc hard enough (e.g. drop it while it is spinning) then whatever part is active can get scratched and unreadable. Inner or outer tracks do not matter in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>[[1]](https://superuser.com/questions/628822/win7-win8-dual-boot-drive-partitioning#comment783918_628871)</sup> If I will be partitioning my Drive, where is the safest place for the very Important Data Files? Do you think Partitions with the lower number is safer than Partitions with the higher number, ie: Partition 2 is better than Partition 5? I've heard that the lower the number, the nearer it is towards the center/core of the disk, and the higher the number, the nearer towards the edge of the disk, is it True? So if that is the case, if in case the disk would fail, what partitions will be first affected?

<sup>[[2]](https://superuser.com/questions/628822/win7-win8-dual-boot-drive-partitioning#comment784163_628871)</sup> For non-SSDs, it is almost always (99.99%) true that it starts from the inside. Which partition is “safe” isn’t usually a valid question because almost always, if the drive fails, then all partitions become inaccessible; there are very few ways that a drive can have a problem where only some are bad and some are good.

That said, drives park their heads in the center of the disk (on the hub). That means that the head spends more time on average over the inner tracks than the outer tracks. Thus, it is “safest” to put critical files on the last partition because it is less likely that the head will actually gouge the outer parts of the platter. Of course this has two implications:

1. Accessing the data in the outer tracks will be slightly slower since most hard-drives are [CAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_Angular_Velocity).
2. The benefit of putting important data on outer tracks only applies if you have sufficiently massive quantities of money to pay to have someone use a [SEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_electron_microscope) to extract the data directly from the platters of the dead drive.

> I once remember my bestfriend who got her disk malfunctioned, we brought it to a technician, and the guy recovered some files on certain parts of the disk, but not all. Well, maybe its just a coincidence that certain parts cannot be recovered, whilst other parts can be.

That is more common with scratched CDs and DVDs. If the scratch is towards the outer edges of the disc, then you can read more data before running into trouble. I suppose the same could apply to a hard-drive, but like Hennes said, if the head dies, then it doesn’t matter where the scratch is on the platter, but if you have enough money, you could get a host drive with a good head to put the platters in and recover the data. In this situation, it could help because the file-system structures are put at the start of the drive, but then if you do signature-based recovery, then it doesn’t matter; you just read the whole drive, copying anything and everything that can be read and hope that some of the recovered files are ones you want.